# Sparks job hangs in multi-node yarn cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I have setup multi-node yarn-cluster

Node-1 : Datanode and master
Node-2 : Datanode

When i submit my job, job works fine when first container is launched on Node-1 but job remains in accepted state when first container is launched on node-2 .Why this happens

On yarn web ui, i can see both nodes registered

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there lack off available required resources to run job on cluster. To verify it check overall resources (cores, RAM) and required/used resources for your single job.
The second one would be able to change state running after first job finished.

Comment: I have checked.. free memory on both nodes is 6GB and no job is in running state. Weird thing is when first container is launched on Node-1 everything goes smooth. Is there any permissions issue. Please let me know if you my core-site.xml or any other files for reference.